# Redirecting mobile directory to www version creating loop

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, jquery-mobile, mod-rewrite

I've been searching for an answer to this question for 2 weeks with no solutions found.

I have a site at www.getgroundedfootwear.com
I have a 301 redirect from the non-www version to the www version in my htaccess file. Works perfectly.

I have a mobile site at www.getgroundedfootwear.com/m/
The non-www version of this mobile directory does NOT redirect to the www version (which is my main problem and I can't understand why the htaccess file in the root does not handle this for me)

The root htaccess file redirects mobile visitors to getgroundedfootwear.com/m/ when it detects the mobile device.

www.getgroundedfootwear.com/m/ redirects to the desktop version when it detects the visitor is on a desktop.

How would I make sure getgroundedfootwear.com/m/ redirects to the www version (www.getgroundedfootwear.com/m/)????

Google is indexing my main site AND our non-www mobile pages. It is driving me insane. Our web developer cannot answer this, my hosting company has been no help, and I am at a loss.

I've properly used canonical as well as alternate robots header tags to tell Google about each version.

Any help is very much appreciated!

htaccess in root of site:

```
#AuthName "Secure Area"
#AuthType Basic
#AuthUserFile /home/getgroun/.htpasswd
#require valid-user
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

  ############################################
  ## adjust memory limit

  #    php_value memory_limit 64M
  php_value memory_limit 256M
  php_value max_execution_time 18000

  ############################################
  ## disable magic quotes for php request vars

  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

  ############################################
  ## disable automatic session start
  ## before autoload was initialized

  php_flag session.auto_start off

  ############################################
  ## enable resulting html compression

  php_flag zlib.output_compression on

  ###########################################
  # disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

  php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

  ###########################################
  # turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

  php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
  ###########################################
  # disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  ############################################
  ## enable apache served files compression
  ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

  # Insert filter on all content
  ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  # Insert filter on selected content types only
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

  # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

  # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

  # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

  # Don't compress images
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

  # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

  ############################################
  ## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

  SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^getgroundedfootwear.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.getgroundedfootwear.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  ############################################

  ## enable rewrites

  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on

  ############################################
  ## you can put here your magento root folder
  ## path relative to web root

  RewriteBase /

  ############################################
  ## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

  #    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

  ############################################
  ## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

  RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

  ############################################
  ## workaround for HTTP authorization
  ## in CGI environment

  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  ############################################
  ## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
  RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

  ############################################
  ## redirect for mobile user agents

  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.getgroundedfootwear.com/m%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

  ############################################
  ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

  ############################################
  ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  ############################################
  ## rewrite everything else to index.php

  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

  ############################################
  ## Add default Expires header
  ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

  ExpiresByType image/* "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/* "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

#FileETag none
FileETag -INode

############################################

  RewriteEngine On
  Redirect 301 /home http://www.getgroundedfootwear.com
```

Mobile htaccess:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for desktop user agents

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ http://www.getgroundedfootwear.com/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: Post your .htaccess code in your question.

Comment: Oops .. just updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess file:**

```
## redirect for mobile user agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule !^m/ http://www.getgroundedfootwear.com/m%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

**/m/.htaccess file:**

```
## append www in hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.getgroundedfootwear.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

## redirect for desktop user agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.getgroundedfootwear.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: I've tried that and it creates a loop. Mobile browsers cannot open it and display a "too many redirects" message. This also doesn't resolve the problem of the non-www version not redirecting to the www version. Search engines are viewing them as 2 different versions.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess inside `/m/` directory also?

Comment: I guess mobile htaccess didn't get posted before. Just added it again to original post. Sorry about that.

Comment: No ideas? I'm at a total loss here. Thanks.

Comment: Just saw your updated code. You need to place above code **in the /m/.htaccess file before any other rule**

Comment: I added the code you pasted above into the /m/ htaccess file (just inder the "rewriteengine on" line) and I get the error "cannot open the page because of too many redirects"

Comment: Just edited code, try it in **/m/.htaccess file before any other rule**

Comment: Instead of creating a loop, it doesn't seem to do anything. No redirect to www, no error.

Comment: ok one more edit, try it now. Also let me know which URL are you trying.

Comment: That solved the problem of redirecting getgroundedfootwear.com/m/ to www.getgroundedfootwear.com if a user is on a desktop device. However, now when I access getgroundedfootwear.com from a mobile device, I get the "cannot open the page because too many redirects occurred".

Comment: Can you totally comment out `redirect for mobile user agents` rule and try from mobile browsers.

Comment: Commented out on /m/ htaccess and still has a loop when accessing getgroundedfootwear.com from a mobile device. Is there something in the htaccess in the root that needs to be updated?

Comment: yes that is also needed. check updated answer, make sure these rules are before other rules.

Comment: Made the changes and still too many redirects from mobile device.

Comment: Probably you have sone duplicate rule. Please edit your question and provide both .htaccess files again.

Comment: Just updated the code in the original posts for both htaccess files. If you can figure this out, you're a genius!

Comment: Why did you place mobile agent rule in `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` section?

Comment: No matter where I put it in the root htaccess file, I get the same result. Mobile device has too many redirects.

Comment: I had a minor typo in my rule: It should be: `RewriteRule !^m/ http://www.getgroundedfootwear.com/m%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]` try it now.

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything. Still too many redirects. If I remove the mobile redirect rule in root htaccess it opens the main site just fine on mobile. Not sure if that helps you at all.

Comment: I give up. Thanks for trying.

Comment: So I've got the redirects working properly without creating a loop. I replaced the code for both htaccess files in the original post above. The only question left is ... how do I get the mobile URL's to redirect to the corresponding desktop page when the browsers detects a desktop device instead of redirecting to the home page of the desktop site? Example: When i type in getgroundedfootwear.com/m/about it should redirect to www.getgroundedfootwear.com/about

Comment: I can add that rule for desktop redirection.

Comment: check the edited rule above for `redirect for desktop user agents`

Comment: Got it working correctly. Thanks for all your help. You had the ! outside the "" designating user agents and I added this in mobile htaccess (slightly different than your recommendation): RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.getgroundedfootwear.com/$1 [L,R=302]

Comment: Great to know it worked for you eventually. Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 0):

That's because /m is recognized as a different path. You could try building a simple index.html in the non-www /m page which redirects to www./m

Comment: I tried adding a redirect in the index.php file in the /m/ directory, but it again creates a loop and there are too many redirects.